# 2 @HostBinding 1 Member in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I Use the following to default a bootstrap class when my component is used. It works perfectly well (angular 6):

```
@Input()
@HostBinding('class.form-control')
hasFormControl: boolean = true;
```

However i want to configure other HostBindings to apply on when the same variable is true, somewhat like this:

```
@Input()
@HostBinding('class.form-control')
hasFormControl: boolean = true;
@HostBinding('class.px-0') this.hasFormControl; // does not compile
```

How to properly do this?

Comment: why do you want to access two properties by one variable ?

Comment: convenience. Of course i would then rename it to reflect whats being done when setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `@HostBinding(...)` more than once to the *same property* to achieve the desired result:

```
@Input()
@HostBinding('class.form-control')
@HostBinding('class.px-0')
hasFormControl: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
_hasFormControl: boolean = true;

@HostBinding('class.form-control')
get classFormControl() { return this._hasFormControl; }
@HostBinding('class.px-0')
get classPx0() { return this._hasFormControl; }
```